# How to remove the highlight words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">

<div id="content">
<p>Hello World!</p>


function doSearch(text) {
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
} else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    while (textRange.findText(text)) {
        textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
        textRange.collapse(false);
    }
}
}
```

Hey guys, I am facing a problem here. How to remove the highlighted word after i press the find button again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if there is already an element which has the highlighted class. if yes then first remove all highlighted spans inside the content div p element.

```
 if(document.querySelector('span[style*="background-color: yellow;"]') !== null) {
        var elem = document.querySelector("#content p");
        var txt = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;
        elem.innerHTML = txt;
   }
```

```js
function doSearch(text) {
  
   if(document.querySelector('span[style*="background-color: yellow;"]') !== null){
        var elem = document.querySelector("#content p");
        var txt = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;
        elem.innerHTML = txt;
   }
  
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
} else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    while (textRange.findText(text)) {
        textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
        textRange.collapse(false);
    }
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">

<div id="content">
<p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```